# c# if else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, mono

i am having a problem with an if-else statement (note: i am fairly inexperienced with programming)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 0 and 10:");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(number > 10)
                Console.WriteLine("Hey! The number should be 10 or less!");
            else
                if(number < 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Hey! The number should be 0 or more!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Good job!");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I use mono for compiling. i got these errors:

> testif.txt(10,11): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
>
> testif.txt(13,9): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `else'

Comment: the problem is in testif.txt not in code that you post here and also use curly braces when you have multi-line if-else

Comment: You must use curly braces when you have multi-line if's and else's:
use {} for the first else

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: I agree with @shadow this should not give an error. I do not have access to Mono compiler right now, but the Visual C# compiler is fine with your code. Are you absolutely sure you do not have an extra `;` after one of the `if` conditions? Also, as hinted in the first comment, the line numbers from Mono do not seem to fit with the code you show.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/5011f09h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You need one line `else if`

```
if(number > 10)
    Console.WriteLine("Hey! The number should be 10 or less!");
else if(number < 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Hey! The number should be 0 or more!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Good job!");
```

Or use `{}`

```
if(number > 10)
    Console.WriteLine("Hey! The number should be 10 or less!");
else
{
    if(number < 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Hey! The number should be 0 or more!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Good job!");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the code in the question works perfectly fine already.

Comment: Your first "solution" repeats the same code the asker already has, only with difference in whitespace. As seen by the C# compiler, that is the same program. Do you know if the Mono compiler issues the warnings the asker claims it does, and do you know if the Mono compiler omits these warnings if you change only whitespace (as above)? I do not have Mono right here.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i don't know why mono complier say _ Possible mistaken empty statement_ but maybe there is somethig which compiler interpret as new stetment.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 0 and 10:");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number =< 10 && number => 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Good job!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("The number needs to be between 0 and 10");

    Console.ReadLine();
```

this code works for u.
&& sign checks if what stands before it and after. if it is true it goes in there. 
then the else statement take all the cases outside 0-10.

Why your code does not work is that u checks for less than 10 witch works but then u do an else statement withouth brackets {} witch you need to surround your code with if u want it to run in the else statement. And this is why you get your error.

without brackets works if there is only one line of code after the statement. like in my code.

Comment: This changes functionality compared to the original code. This does not explain why the original code should not be OK.

Comment: it was my first solution so im kinda new. thanks for the tip